# SSH and HTTP/S to vbox guest without port forwarding?

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have a Windows 10 host and I'm using Virtual Box to run a Debian 9 guest, which I use for website development.

I have the Debian guest set up to use a NAT adapter, with the following port forwarding:

```
HTTP  127.0.0.1  8080  10.0.2.15  80
HTTPS 127.0.0.1  443   10.0.2.15  443
SSH   127.0.0.1  2022  10.0.2.15  22
```

From the Windows host, I can ssh in to the Debian guest like so:

```
ssh -p 2022 127.0.0.1
```

And I can access the websites I'm developing by adding the forwarded port number to the URL:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080
```

However, I personally find it annoying to remember to add the port number.

I tried ssh'ing in to `10.0.2.15` on both ports `20` and `2022`, but that timed out. I guess that's not actually hitting the guest, just staying in the host internal network.

Is there a way I can configure everything so that the guest has a local 
IP address, so that I can ssh into it, and pull up websites from it, without specifying a non-standard port? I also need access to the outside internet from within the vbox guest, in order to do my development and update the guest OS.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the instructions here: https://dev.to/isabolic99/how-to-set-host-only-adapter-on-vm-virtual-box-2jka . It has instructions about adding additional Host Network settings, but I just went with the default, and it worked fine.

Here are the steps I took:

1. Add a Host-Only Network Adapter to your Debian 9 guest vm.
2. Boot into the vm guest, and determine the name of the new network adapter

   $ ls /sys/class/net

Mine was `enp0s8`.

3. Add the following to your `/etc/network/interfaces`:

   auto enp0s8
   allow-hotplug enp0s8
   iface enp0s8 inet static
   address 192.168.56.11
   netmask 255.255.255.0
4. restart your vm, or use the `ifup enp0s8` command.

Now, from your host machine, you should be able to access the vbox guest at `192.168.56.11` on all the standard ports.